# Qual é o gênero do substantivo personagem?

Tags: concordância, concordância-nominal, gênero

Qual é a classificação do substantivo `personagem` em relação ao seu gênero?

As frases seguintes estão corretas ou incorretas?

> Pedro é o personagem principal.
>   Pedro é a personagem principal.
>   Maria é o personagem principal.
>   Maria é a personagem principal.

Answer (score 10):

Ambas são possíveis. Em Portugal, o género feminino é mais comum. No CETEMPúblico, `"a|as|da|das|à|às|uma|umas|duma|dumas" [lema="personagem"]` dá-me 7888 ocorrências, enquanto `"o|os|do|dos|ao|aos|um|uns|dum|duns" [lema="personagem"]` me dá 2451 ocorrências. Isto corresponde mais ou menos à minha sensibilidade no uso oral da palavra, embora talvez esperasse uma diferença mais marcada (dizer "aquele gajo é um personagem" não me soa nada bem).

Citando uma [entrada no FLiP](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=662):

> Acontece que o uso da palavra pelos falantes ou a influência do género masculino em francês levaram a que a palavra já esteja registada em obras lexicográficas de referência como palavra feminina ou masculina (por exemplo, no Vocabulário da Língua Portuguesa (1966) de Rebelo Gonçalves, no Dicionário da Língua Portuguesa Contemporânea (2001), da Academia das Ciências/Verbo, no Dicionário Houaiss da Língua Portuguesa (2002), do Círculo de Leitores, ou no Grande Dicionário Língua Portuguesa (2004), da Porto Editora).

Parece-me que a questão não é tanto influência do francês, mas que algumas pessoas tendem a dizer "o personagem" quando se trata de uma personagem do sexo masculino e "a personagem" quando é uma mulher. Alterar o género da palavra consoante o sexo da personagem não se pode contudo considerar *standard* na língua.

A razão para a preferência pelo feminino deve dever-se à analogia com outros nomes terminados em "-agem", que geralmente são femininos (ao contrário do francês em "-age"), como "coragem", "viagem", "bagagem", "folhagem", "carruagem", "bobagem", "aragem", "passagem", "portagem", "vagem, "viragem", "paisagem", ....

Comment: Eu acho que simplesmente os falantes são atraídos para aquilo que soa diferente. Dizer "o personagem" soa diferente porque contraria aquilo que é expectável de um substantivo terminado em "agem".

Answer (score 1):

Vale ressaltar que a personagem vem de persona(gênero feminino) observação que utilizo para não cometer gafes, rs. Mesmo a palavra atualmente ser aceita em ambos os gêneros, continuo me atendo a essa regrinha de alfabetização inicial que me foi ensinado. 
 Exemplo de aplicação na regra de gênero feminino: não consegui definir se esta é realmente a sua personalidade ou apenas uma persona criada para fins ilusórios(discernir/discernir).
Bons estudos!

Comment: Tubo - tubagem, peso - pesagem, cavalo - cavalagem, filtro - filtragem, pedal - pedalagem, pirata - piratagem. É feminino mesmo por terminar em -agem.